# C# Equivalent of Xaml's CommandParameter="{Binding .}"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am writing some of my User Interface code in C#. It has **ListView** with `ItemSource` as `List<MyClass>`. When I click on a cell, I want to pass the whole object of `MyClass` to the binded command.

While I was developing it in XAML, I came across CommandParameter="{Binding .}". Doing this I was able to send whole object.

```
 <Label.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.MyId, Source={x:Reference MyList}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

I want to know the c# equivalent of `"{Binding .}"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending almost hours of applying all sort of permutation and combination, here is the "trick" that worked for me:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, modelProperty.Name, BindingMode.TwoWay);
TapGestureRecognizer tgr= new TapGestureRecognizer
{
  Command = BindingContext.CellClickedCommand,
};
tgr.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
lbl.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);
```

I think microsoft must provide better documents for Xamarin forms, as not all developers are working with XAML all the time. Also most of the documents are not with MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to bind the `CommandParameterProperty` of a `TapGestureRecognizer` to a Label's `Text` property using C#

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    var labelTappedGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command<string>(async labelText => await DisplayAlert("Label Tapped", labelText, "OK"))
    };

    var myLabel = new Label
    {
        Text = "This is my label",
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };

    myLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(labelTappedGestureRecognizer);
    labelTappedGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding(nameof(Label.Text), source: myLabel));

    Content = myLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"{Binding .}"` simply equals to `new Binding(".")`. But `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` equals to `tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding(".")).

Comment: I have tried this, but on my command method I am getting and binding object with path = "." . Well this makes sence but I want to get whole row object of MyClass.

Comment: @PranayDeep Ok, I know what you wanted. I will update my answer.